# Sinhala unicode install debian / kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, fonts, unicode

Kali linux (Debian) can't see Sinhala fonts in Chrome or Firefox. It shows as boxes. How can I install Sinhala unicode?

Comment: Did you read the bit on the Debian tag? "Questions specific to the Debian official distribution (stable, testing, or unstable); if you are using a derivative of Debian (e.g. Mint, Ubuntu, Kali, etc), then use that distribution’s tag instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install following packages.

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-lklug-sinhala ibus im-switch ibus-m17n m17n-db m17n-contrib
```

**EDIT** updated answer 2019/03

`sudo apt-get install fonts-lklug-sinhala ibus im-config ibus-m17n m17n-db`

**Remember to Restart the PC**

Ref:
[nongnu sinhala how to](http://www.nongnu.org/sinhala/doc/howto/sinhala-howto.html)
[sinhala-unicode-wijesekara-keyboard-in-ibus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459349/sinhala-unicode-wijesekara-keyboard-in-ibus-on-ubuntu-14-04-not-working)